# D-Class Amplifier Design Verification

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, ltspice

I have an internship coming up working with comparators and amplifiers, so I wanted to take on a side project involving both of those components. Designing a D-Class amplifier seemed like a great way to get some experience making a more involved pcb layout, but before that, I wanted to verify that my schematic is ok. Below is the circuit I came up with.

[image: LTspice Schematic Screenshot] 
LTspice Schematic

[Link to LTspice schematic (google drive)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1OsYa2gvLB0C21ebMZCWuL9M2NrOrw0Jz)

Inputs are a 1Vp-max audio signal from an audio jack and a 200kHz triangle wave. 
For the triangle wave I am planning on using [a SN54LS624 VCO](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74ls628.pdf). Audio inputs are offset ~.1V in in order to cause dead time for minimization of shoot through current of the amplifier FETs.

For my PWM I'm using [a pair of LT1819s](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/18189fb.pdf), chosen for high slew rate and ability to handle 200kHz without issue.

For the gate drivers I'm using [LTC4440-5](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/44405fb.pdf), chosen for its voltage output range. I've never worked or learned about a gate driver prior to this, so it's possible that I'm grossly misusing it. High side driver ranges from -20 to 42V, while low side ranges from -20V to 4V. Is there a way to change this? I don't think it's necessary to bia my NMOS at 42/-20V, and doing so might damage them at worst or slow them down at best. Is this something I'm missing or is my design valid thus far? **I know that dual high side and low side drivers exist, and can have built in dead time, should I consider using one of those instead?**

Power MOSFETs are [IPB136N08N3](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/196/IPP139N08N3_Rev2.5-97962.pdf), chosen for Vds max of 80V, and Vgs max of +-20V. My high side gate driver biases with a Vgs max of 22V, yet another reason I think I'm messing that bit up.

Filter is a 3rd order low pass with a cutoff of 23kHz and attenuation of -45dB at 200kHz. Initially I had a 2nd order but was noticing a low signal to noise ratio at the lower input voltages (Input = 0.5Vp).

Project is planned to use two 20V 3.25A DC power supplies, using diodes for 5V and ~1V (1V for offset and potentially for tri-gen). I've never had any experience with power supplies, so this is another shaky area for me.

---

Other concerns are current spikes in the push-pull NMOS show below. I don't think it's a big deal as each spike is ~25-50ns long, so maybe that's just the simulation being really precise and wouldn't happen in reality but I'm not sure.

[image: Power MOS current spikes]

^Power dissipation on high side NMOS

---

[image: Zoomed In]
^Zoomed into spike, lasts approx 50ns

Comment: LTC4440 are high side drivers, and TS can only go to -5v wrt GND, so your -20v low side FET supply won't work. Might be better to use a dedicated low side driver for M2. LT1819 is an opamp, not a comparator. They are designed to do different things, so read the data sheet carefully and compare to a similarly fast comparator.

Comment: Your audio input impedance is only 100uF||487 ohms. Why such a low impedance? It is not to have ultra-low Johnson noise, as your source baseline noise level could be much higher, unless you use a 24 bit or 32 bit audio source.

Comment: Your LTC4440 inputs cannot go below ground, yet your op-amps are driving the inputs with signals that swing below ground by several volts. You need to re-think your entire design.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks for the catch on the op-amp, annoyingly it's listed on LT under comparators, but now I see the bold text in the data sheet say "don't use as comparator". Replaced that with a LTC6752-2 dedicated comparator. I see the problem with the gate driver, but I'm having trouble fixing it. I want there to be zero DC offset on the output, but every gate driver seems to work for a Vdd to GND. Would a low side driver be to swing my output from +20 to -20V

Comment: No lowside drivers I've come across use a voltage swing like that, you might be able to get away with a 20v swing between -20 and GND, though a dedicated 12-15v supply wrt to the -20v would enable almost any lowside to work. A fully isolated driver would also work, but they too require dedicated rails to power their outputs.

Comment: I see this is a quite old question, but just for grins let me say that you won't need a negative supply at all if you use a full bridge driver where the output is differential rather than being ground referenced.  If you are driving a floating load, you can still drive single ended without a negative supply if you capacitor couple the output.  With a high power level that may take a monstrous cap though.

Comment: @gnuarm Yep, that's what I ended up doing. That and an IC with low side and high side gate drives/ built in dead-time. I also stoped using cascaded zeners for power supply regulation lol

Comment: @Michael - What IC did you use?  I'm trying to drive a speaker, but the amps are either 5V only or are large and cumbersome.  I also have a requirement to measure the speaker current to tell if it is open/shorted.  I looked at other H-bridge drivers which are mostly motor drivers (unsure if they will work at 264 kHz) or FET drivers which are designed for high voltage with boost circuits and high voltage isolation on the high side drive.  Neither facilitate measuring the state of the speaker.  Currently I'm simulating a full bridge using six transistors per speaker (two for level shifting).